# Как вывести запросом из БД минимальное и максимальное значение?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Здраствуйте, не могу понять, объясните пожалуйста

Есть запрос к БД MySQL, через PDO:

```
$cmd = $this->pdo->query("SELECT id, title, category, date_added, city, in_top, language, type, building_condition, rooms, bathrooms,
MIN(price) as min($min_price), photo, photo_2, photo_3, photo_4 
FROM $database_lang WHERE city = $city and in_top = $in_top 
ORDER BY id $new LIMIT $entry_start, ".LIMIT_ENTRY."");
```

Но не могу вывести минимальную и максимальную цену (price)
То есть, в поиске ставится значение, к примеру 50000 и чтобы вывелись все записи квартир у которых цена не меньше 50000

Как это реализовать?

Comment: _в поиске ставится значение, к примеру 50000 и чтобы вывелись все записи квартир у которых цена не меньше 50000_ `... WHERE price >= 50000`

Comment: На будущее, ПДО не исполняет твои запросы. А только отправляет их в базу данных и возвращает результат. А исполняет запросы база данных

Comment: ну и вопрос противоречит заголовку, что делает его бессмысленным

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Напишу чтоб было читабельнее сам запрос а вы поставите как надо.  Если я правильно понял и вам нужны сами квартиры то нужно использовать оконные функции. Так как вам нужны только min и мах то можно сделать так.

```
SELECT 
     id, 
     title, 
     category, 
     date_added, 
     city, 
     in_top, 
     language, 
     type, 
     building_condition, 
     rooms, 
     bathrooms, 
     price, 
     photo, 
     photo_2, 
     photo_3, 
     photo_4 
FROM 
     $database_lang 
WHERE 
     city = $city 
     and price >= 50000
ORDER BY price desc
LIMIT 1
UNION ALL
SELECT 
     id, 
     title, 
     category, 
     date_added, 
     city, 
     in_top, 
     language, 
     type, 
     building_condition, 
     rooms, 
     bathrooms, 
     price, 
     photo, 
     photo_2, 
     photo_3, 
     photo_4 
FROM 
     $database_lang 
WHERE 
     city = $city 
     and price >= 50000
ORDER BY price
LIMIT 1
```

Можно сделать одним запросом без union тогда нужно будет отбросить данные о квартирах и оставить только цену потому что агрегирование работает с однородными данными.

Comment: Разобрался, спасибо)

Answer (score 0):

Надо запросить минимальное и максимальное значение цены

```
$sql = "SELECT min(price), max(price) FROM database_lang WHERE price > ?";
$stmt = $this->pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute([$price]);
list($min, $max) = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ROW);
```

По желанию можно добавить в запрос другие условия

То есть если нужно получить минимальное и максимальное значение цен, которые будут в выборке по заданным условиям без лимита, то надо выполнить отдельный запрос.